# Python 3.X - Search a list using user input and print the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

```
with open("zipcodes.txt", "r") as ins:
   array = []
   for line in ins:
       array.append(line.split(","))

print(array)

userInput = input("Please enter the codes your looking for: ")

print(array.index(userInput))
```

First off, this is for a school assignment, so I am not looking for a complete answer, I'm looking for a direction. My assignment is to load in a text file into a list, separate each line. (the text file is every USA zip code, the city the zipcode is for, and the state EX. 93312,BAKERSFIELD,CA). once the list is created the next thing the program needs to do is take in a users zipcode and then print out the zipcode, the city and the state. This is the code I have so far, I am at a total loss of what to do. Again I am not looking for a complete answer, just a direction. Sometimes I miss simple solutions and just need someone to say something that will make it click in my head. Thank you for your time and for any info or help.

Comment: Is this giving you errors?

Comment: Every line you loop through you reinitialize your "array" as `array=[]` so it will only contain the last line

Comment: `ins.close()` isn't needed since it was opened with a context manager

Comment: @kstullich I get an error from the print line using the userInput

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce I wasn't too sure on that so added it anyways, thank you for the correction

Comment: @quantik whenever the print(array) line runs it shows me all the zipcodes in the file though, not just the last one

Comment: @MarcusHartline you are correct I misread it due to the formatting. One piece of advice I have in addition to that is because you have a list of lists and the zipcode is presumably the first element of each list, is to only query that based on the user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This version doesn't use a dictionary but uses a list instead.

This code is a quick example of one way you could do that. The file `zipcodes.txt` only has that single example that you gave in the description.

```
MATCH = """
Zipcode: {}
City:    {}
State:   {}
"""

with open('zipcodes.txt', 'r') as f:
    zipcodes = [line.rstrip().split(',') for line in f]

while True:
    user_zipcode = input("Enter zipcode (or (Q)uit): ")
    if user_zipcode.lower() == 'q':
        break
    for zipcode, city, state in zipcodes:
        if user_zipcode == zipcode:
            print(MATCH.format(zipcode, city, state))
            break
    else:
        print("\nNo match for zipcode: '{}'\n".format(user_zipcode))
```

Console:

```
Enter zipcode (or (Q)uit): 12345

No match for zipcode: '12345'

Enter zipcode (or (Q)uit): 93312

Zipcode: 93312
City:    BAKERSFIELD
State:   CA

Enter zipcode (or (Q)uit): q
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and for the help. Unfortunately my instructor stated that it must only be done using a list or lists.

Comment: If it is not too much trouble, I am very new to coding and really want to understand it and any help I can get is surely appreciated. I have been doing excellent up until this assignment, dealing with list is stumping me for some reason.

Comment: thank you very much. I'll see if I can run through this myself and figure all that is going on and what its doing. Really do appreciate the help and will for sure ask if I dont understand something.

Answer (score 2):

array.index() does not return the element itself; It returns at which index it is. For example, if '93267' is the second element in a list and you called array.index('93267'), you'd get '1'. Try creating a variable that holds the index, and then print whatever is *at that* index:

```
index1 = array.index(userInput)
print(array[index1))
```

Yet you may run into an issue with this, as in your code you split each line at a comma- and in your description, your postcode, city and state were separated by a comma. I'm not entirely sure what your original text file looks like, so I could be wrong, but just be aware that it may cause some issues down the track.

Hope this helped; if you run into more issues, feel free to say so. Good luck with your school project!

Comment: Using this method it returned the same error as before, I believe its because of the way I am saving the file into a list, creating a sublist for each line. I am not sure though i could be totally wrong

Comment: @MarcusHartline What's the error you are seeing when you run your program?

Comment: For me I am getting not in range of list error or not in list error

Comment: @MarcusHartline This is most likely because you have a list of lists. When you try to find the index of '93267', you will be told it's not in the list because it itself is not an element of a single list- it's an element of a list of a list. Instead you could check to see if each list in 'array' has a matching index[0] to the zipcode entered (using a for loop).

Comment: was able to figure out how to get this working thanks to your "using a for loop" comment it actually helped a lot. Thank you very much for the help and for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, the structure of `array` will end up like this:

[['ZIPCODE', 'CITY', 'STATE'], ['ZIPCODE', 'CITY', 'STATE'], ...]

and `userInput` will hold a string representing a ZIPCODE.

Given that structure of `array`, for each entry in `array` (each sublist), the first element in the entry (entry[0]) will be a ZIPCODE.

You could loop through each entry in `array`, and check if that entry's first element matches the `userInput`.

If it does, you can print that entry.

Note: To understand why you are getting an error from the print statement, please check this description of [**list methods**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), namely the `index` method.

Comment: Thank you for the information I will be testing this method right now and see if I can get it working for my situation.

Comment: @MarcusHartline Let me know how you did or if I can be of any further assistance.

Comment: I took the information you gave me and coupled it with information that others gave me and I was finally able to come up with a working result, it needs fine tuning but its actually working now. Thank you for your time and help! Truly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to do it. And hopefully learning something in the process :D

Comment: Actually learned some valuable information that ended up helping me on a previous in class assignment as well so I am very very thankful for the help I received here. Excellent community! Glad I asked the question! Thank you again!